# Inconsistent manual computing of cumsumming a array in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I know Python starts initial index of a array from `0` and I also know `x[:,:k]` means first `k` column of array `x`, then I try

```py
## prepare array
x = np.array([1, -2, 0, -2, 5, 0, 0, 0, 2]).reshape(3,-1) 
x

## use cumsum
x1 = np.cumsum(x,axis=1)
x1

## manually compute
x2 = np.zeros(x.shape) 
for k in range(x.shape[1]):
  x2[:,k] = np.sum(x[:,:k],axis=1) 

x2
```

However, I found `x1` is inconsistent with `x2`. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using numpy in loops in not a recommended way, particularly when numpy have equivalent modules. But, in case of this question, you can do this as:

```
x2 = np.zeros(x.shape)
for k in range(x.shape[1]):
    for j in range(x.shape[0]):
        x2[k, j] = np.sum(x[k, :j+1])
```

or if `axis=0`:

```
x2 = np.zeros(x.shape)
for k in range(x.shape[1]):
    for j in range(x.shape[0]):
        x2[j, k] = np.sum(x[:j+1, k])
```

If you want to know how to modify your code, you must use `k+1` instead of `k` in `np.sum` because range is starting from `0` --> `:k` will be `:0` ==> `:k+1` will be `:1`

```
x2 = np.zeros(x.shape)
for k in range(x.shape[1]):
  x2[:, k] = np.sum(x[:, :k+1], axis=1)
```

Comment: Your third reply is exact my solution!  Very impresive! @Ali_Sh However, unlike R and Matlab, the way in Python is a little bit violation of common-sense,  where `x2[:, 0]` means the first column while `x[:, :0]` is `[]` set.

Comment: It seems that `x[:, :k]` equals `x[:,0:k]` only for `k≠0`, while `x[:, :1]` and `x[:,0]` both mean the first column of array `x`.

Comment: @JohnStone True

Answer (score 2):

```
In [20]: x = np.array([1, -2, 0, -2, 5, 0, 0, 0, 2]).reshape(3,-1)

In [21]: x
Out[21]: 
array([[ 1, -2,  0],
       [-2,  5,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  2]])
```

`x` is symmetric, but the cumsum is not.

```
In [22]: np.cumsum(x,axis=1)
Out[22]: 
array([[ 1, -1, -1],
       [-2,  3,  3],
       [ 0,  0,  2]], dtype=int32)
```

The first column is the same as in `x`.  The 2nd is `x[:,0]+x[:,1]`, etc.

Change the axis, and the result is just the transpose.

```
In [23]: np.cumsum(x,axis=0)
Out[23]: 
array([[ 1, -2,  0],                # x[0,:]
       [-1,  3,  0],                # x[0,:]+x[1,:]
       [-1,  3,  2]], dtype=int32)
```

We can iterate across the columns with:

```
In [25]: res = np.zeros((3,3),int)
    ...: res[:,0] = x[:,0]
    ...: for i in range(1,3):
    ...:     res[:,i] = res[:,i-1] + x[:,i]
    ...:     

In [26]: res
Out[26]: 
array([[ 1, -1, -1],
       [-2,  3,  3],
       [ 0,  0,  2]])
```

Your iteration is has `0` in the first column, not `x[:,0]`:

```
In [27]: res = np.zeros((3,3),int)
    ...: for i in range(0,3):
    ...:     res[:,i] = x[:,:i].sum(axis=1)
    ...:     

In [28]: res
Out[28]: 
array([[ 0,  1, -1],
       [ 0, -2,  3],
       [ 0,  0,  0]])
```

That's because the `:i` does not include `i`.

```
In [29]: res = np.zeros((3,3),int)
    ...: for i in range(0,3):
    ...:     res[:,i] = x[:,:i+1].sum(axis=1)
    ...:     

In [30]: res
Out[30]: 
array([[ 1, -1, -1],
       [-2,  3,  3],
       [ 0,  0,  2]])
```